# why isnt the background clearing the circle?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want a ball falling, with gravity. But the background won't clear the previous circle. (the falling part isnt implemented yet) why doesnt it erase the last drawn object?

```
let c, ctx;
let met;

let colorArray = ["green", "yellow", "orange", "red"];

window.onload = function(){
    c = document.getElementById("boom");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    c.width = window.innerWidth - 165;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;

    setup();
    draw();
}

function setup(){
    met = new Meteor(200, 400, 10, 0, 5);
}


function draw(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    ctx.fillStyle = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    met.draw();
    met.fall();
};


class Meteor {
    constructor(x, y, r, xSpeed, ySpeed){
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;

        this.radius = r;

        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;

        this.color = "blue";

        this.acceleration = 0.5;

    }

    draw(){
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        //ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    fall(){
        this.yPos += (this.ySpeed);
    }

}
```

Also, if you have any tips on how to make it have gravity, please don't hesitate to tell me. Ive been struggling with it for a while now.

Comment: Add `ctx.beginPath();` before drawing the ball. To emulate gravity, you need to increase the y-coordinate relative to the time: `y = v0*t + (a*t**2)/2`.

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqvwyg6f/) shows how you can use gravity. It's a bit messy, I'd suggest you to enclose all the functions within the class, that would make the code clearer. Notice, that `ySpeed` is now rather scaling the gravity speed to the screen than presenting the actual speed, the gravity formula calculates the actual speed.

Answer (score 1):

In `draw()` add this before the call to `met.draw()`:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innterHeight)
```

This will clear the screen every frame.

For gravity, add a `dt` parameter to your draw function, then pass it to `met.draw()` like this:

```
function draw(dt){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    ctx.fillStyle = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innterHeight) // Clear screen here
    met.draw(dt);
    met.fall();
};
```

Then in the `Meteor` class, use the `dt` in the `draw()` function to calculate your y position based on velocity. Here `dt` will be your delta time for the calculation.